# Magento static block issue in 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento, static, block, upgrade

I just have upgraded my store to latest CE 1.9.2.2 and my static blocks called on home page are not more there.

I tried both ways to implement but in vain.

1) In home page layout update section

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home-popular" template="catalog/product/popular_list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

2) In cms content area

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/popular_list.phtml"}}
```

I remember we had block cache issue in 1.9.1.x

can you please guide me what could be the issue?

Comment: popular_list.phtml template exists ?
try thisone for test
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. In that new version the block include in CMS is blocked. You have to set permissions first. That is very very annoying especially if that is your AGB for block for example. You can fix that problem when you go to

```
System -> Permissions -> Blocks
```

There you add a new entry named `cms/block` and set them to `Allowed`. Then you get your blocks back.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stony works like a charm but I couldn't understand the purpose of this new feature :(

Comment: I don't know its very risky vor people that don't know that and install the new update and get a lot of trouble because they haven't seen that the legal rights pages aren't shown correctly. Thats not a feature thats a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Add catalog/product_list to the System -> Permissions -> Blocks

Block name: catalog/product_list
is Allowed: yes